# ES6 Class constructor not working in nodejs 4.4.5LTS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to write a fake downloader which basically sleeps for certain interval and emits a 'downloaded' event. I also want to have **my own variable** that tracks the number of events emitted.
This piece of code throws the following error:

```
ReferenceError: this is not defined
```

Code:

```
'use strict';
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class Downloader extends EventEmitter{
    constructor(){
        this.totalEmitted = 0;
    }
    download(delaySecs){
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.emit('downloaded',delaySecs);
            this.totalEmitted ++;
        },delaySecs*1000)
    }
}

module.exports = Downloader;
```

where as, if I comment **this.totalEmitted**, it works fine.

**UPDATE:**

When I completely eliminate the constructor it started working fine.

***And even using an empty constructor is causing the this Reference error.***

I'm not sure if the constructor is yet supported in node 4.4.5.

Work around:

```
'use strict';
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class Downloader extends EventEmitter{
    download(delaySecs){
        setTimeout(() => {
            if(this.totalEmitted == undefined) this.totalEmitted = 0;
            this.totalEmitted ++;
            this.emit('downloaded',delaySecs,this.totalEmitted);            
        },delaySecs*1000)
    }
}

module.exports = Downloader;
```

Comment: Don't use arrow functions if you need `this` inside them. Try to rewrite it into regular function

Comment: @vicodin, actually in this case not using an arrow function would cause issues.  user3151330 wants the outer `this` (the `this` of `download`).  A regular function would have to be bound or use a value from a higher scope to get to the `Downloader` instance in the `setTimeout` callback.

Comment: true, my apologies

Comment: have you tried add super() in your constructor?

Comment: or add .bind(this) to the setTimeout?

Comment: @jamesemanon you hit the bull's eye. Adding super is working. And it corresponds to the ES5 version of EventEmitter.call(this). But I still do not understand why javascript is not able to establish a this for the class itself. There is no such rule in ES6.

Comment: Inside a child class, `this` is not initialized until `super()` is called.

Comment: dang, I should of added it as an answer! lol.. I need those points! hahha.. glad to help!

Comment: @loganfsmyth Even using an empty constructor in subclass throws this error. So, if I have to call a `super()` inside a sub class constructor to initialize this, why shouldn't Javascript automatically take care of it? What is the need of we writing it?

Comment: What if you want to pass different options to the parent class?

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't bother you so much switching from ES6 Class to functions, then you could try:

```
'use strict';
const util = require('util');
const EventEmitter = require('events');

function Downloader() {
  var self = this;

  self.totalEmitted = 0;

  this.on('downloaded', function() {
    self.totalEmitted ++;
    console.log(self.totalEmitted);
  });
}

util.inherits(Downloader, EventEmitter);

Downloader.prototype.download = function(delaySecs) {
  setTimeout(() => {
      this.emit('downloaded', delaySecs);
  }, delaySecs*1000);
};

var downloader = new Downloader();
downloader.download(1);

module.exports = Downloader;
```